# Can't get Ruby on Rails 4 Ajax working with Checkbox -Update Firing: but isn't changing checkbox or database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm attempting to use Ajax with Ruby on Rails 4 to watch when the checkbox changes and submit the form and save the checkbox change to the database. Even with the debugger I'm not seeing any errors. Any thoughts?

I recently changed the path to edit because I was getting a 404. I did this to it matches a route.

I just added the success function to the ajax call and it appears to be firing.

This is what I have currently:

This is product_controller

```
def update
  if @product.update(safe_params)
    redirect_to [:edit, @product], flash: { notice: t('shoppe.products.update_notice') }
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

This is form in haml

```
= form_for product, :remote => true do |f|
    = f.check_box :active
    = f.label :active,  t('shoppe.products.active'), :remote => true
```

This is js:

```
$('#product_active').bind('change', function() {
    console.log('changed');
    var action = $(this).parents('form').attr('action')+"/edit";
    var method = "GET";
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    var data = $(this).attr('value');
    data ^= 1;

    $.ajax({
      method: method,
      url: action,
      data: checked,
      success: function() {
        alert("AJAX Fired");  
      }
    })

    debugger;

});
```

This is from rake routes

```
products     GET      /products(.:format)            shoppe/products#index
             POST     /products(.:format)            shoppe/products#create
new_product  GET      /products/new(.:format)        shoppe/products#new
edit_product GET      /products/:id/edit(.:format)   shoppe/products#edit
product      GET      /products/:id(.:format)        shoppe/products#show
             PATCH    /products/:id(.:format)        shoppe/products#update
             PUT      /products/:id(.:format)        shoppe/products#update
             DELETE   /products/:id(.:format)
```

UPDATE: I ended up putting a hidden submit button with the form and changing my js to and adding in a class to the form to allow me to hit all ajax with one set of code:

```
$('.ajax').bind('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I ended up putting a hidden submit button with the form and changing my js to and adding in a class to the form to allow me to hit all ajax with one set of code:

Answer (score 0):

You need to hit the `update` endpoint of your routes not the edit. The edit route is usually to load the edit view.

You'll also want to return a json encoded response in the update action and handle the `success` jquery callback and from there you would redirect in the client side or do whatever you want to do to update the UI. A redirect would be only useful from within your rails code if you were actually submitting a form and not doing ajax.